# Execute a background process after typing a command

Tags: linux, shell, automation, command-prompt

I want to autorun a shell script after i type a command. For example  i am running helm test ...  in this case let go the task it does , but before that, I need to autorun a shell script  configures variables to change them in helm's templates.

Is there a way to do this automation task, combining some commands maybe? I dont want a  cron job because this won't be a scheduled task, only will be executed after user run helm test, I mean interrupt the process it does itself for get time to let changing variables in template running the shell script.

I did it in this way beacuse I need to extract data from kubernetes output. Other idea? Because I saw a reference using PROMPT_COMMAND variable, I am discovering how.

Comment: press `control` and `z` it will send the program to process in the background, just type in `bg` to bring it back to the foreground

Comment: Command prompt is unfortunately a very broad concept on Linux / Unix-based systems. Do you mean an local terminal on your Linux-PC ? Or do you mean remote connection to the terminal (SSH / Telnet protocol) ? Different rules apply there. If you close the terminal (Shell i.e. command-line interpreter) in which your script is running in the background, it will be interrupted. The same applies to the acquired variables in this terminal connection. If you use shell-script, then it depends on how you run it. Command can be run in the background in many ways (e.g. add the `&` character at the end).

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen `fg` to return the process to the foreground rather than `bg`.